# How to prevent webView from opening new tab on middle mouse button click

Tags: c#, .net, web, webview, maui

I use Web View in MAUI in my .net application.
When user click on the link with middle mouse button (or regular click with shift pressed) a new window is pop up.

And this is want I want to prevent.
I need my custom action on this event.

What I tried :

- Use js to set events on page
- Subscribe to MAUI events like OnWindowCreated

Edit :
I Tried to catch middle mouse lick with in low level style with OnPlatformMessage in ConfigureLifecycleEvents but failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this Issues like this :

Create custom WebView like that:

```
#if WINDOWS
    public class CustomWebView : WebView
    {
    ... code
    }
#else
    public class CustomWebView : WebView
    {
    }
#endif
```

Than I put this methods inside to catch tapped event :

```
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();

        // Check if the handler is available and it is a specific platform handler
        if (Handler?.PlatformView is WebView2 webView)
        {
            webView.Tapped += WebView_Tapped;
            webView.NavigationStarting += WebView_NavigationStarting; ;
        }
    }
```

In tapped I get CoreWebView2 and add handler on newWindowRequested event like this :

```
    private void WebView_Tapped(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView2 senderWebView = sender as WebView2;

        // Unsubscribe the event handler if it's already subscribed
        senderWebView.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested -= CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;

        // sucbscribe
        senderWebView.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;
    }
```

Than I handle new window requested to disallow new window to pop Up by marking requested as handled and raise event to handle this action with my logic instead of aperaing new WebView window :

```
    private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2 sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Create an event argument object to pass data to the event handler
        var eventArgs = args.Uri;
        // Raise the custom event
        OnNewWindowRequested(eventArgs);

        args.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a demo based on JavaScript for you to refer to. You can see that the first method uses to prevent the new window to popup after using the 'ctrl + leftclick'. The second method uses to prevent the new window to popup after clicking the middle mouse button.

```
<html>
<body>
   
     <a href="https:// links here /">click this link!</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

    let links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    // prevent to start the webview by using the 'ctrl + leftclick'
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            if (e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }  
    // prevent to start the webview by using the middle mouse click
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].addEventListener('auxclick', function (e) {
            if (e.which === 2 || e.button === 1) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        })  

    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use [the WebView to present the html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/single-project?view=net-maui-8.0#raw-assets) above. First, you need to put the html file in the Resource/raw folder of your project. Second, its build action will be set to `MauiAsset`.

```
<WebView Source="app1.html" />
```

Comment: OK, its work in very simple case, but what if i have buttons, and div elements that too redirecting on something. And with middle mouse button click also opening new window.

Comment: You can package these codes into functions. In this way, you just use the function when you want to prevent the WebView page popup.

Comment: I not sure what you mean. also i notices this is working only for initial state, its dont working on all link who will appear during work after initial load.

Comment: I mean you can create your own function of the JavaScript to prevent the webview popup. I just provided a simple demo for you to refer to.  In this case, I used the `document.getElementsByTagName('a');` but you can change it to button or other elements. Besides, Can you provide some scenarios which you want to prevent the popup?

Comment: Can I set event like this globally, so any popup from basic browser behaviour will be prevented from showing?

Comment: Yes, you can set it globally.

Comment: i sad like that and its dont work

            document.addEventListener('auxclick', function (e) {
                if (e.which === 2 || e.button === 1) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }

I thing use js for this bad idea. I need some how customized WebView.